# Sorting table entries automatically

Tags: tables, automation, sorting

As one part of my thesis, I have more than 20 tables. I need to sort their entries alphabetically.

The tables are in following format:

```
\begin{table}
  \label{tab:first}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    Language  & Syllable &  IPA & VIS & VDS & CS &  CVS \\ \hline
    Malayalam & k        & k    & \Mal{ഈ}\normalfont   & \Mal{ീ}\normalfont  iː & \Mal{ക} \normalfont k   & \Mal{കീ}\normalfont    kiː \\
    Tamil        & ~        & ~    & ~   & ~   & ~  & ~    \\
    Kannada        & ~        & ~    & ~   & ~   & ~  & ~    \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table contains syllable in IPA, VIS-Vowel Independent Syllable, VDS-Vowel Dependent Symbol, CS-Consonant Symbol, and CVS  Consonant with Vowel Symbol.}
\end{table}
```

I need to sort the tables according to the content of first column. Any specific package or macro for that purpose.

Comment: would an external script (e.g. in `python`) an acceptable option?

Comment: Yes, it will be perfect

Comment: If all of these tables are in final form and will not have any significant future changes in the first column, then for time efficiency you may be best served with a manual sort.  (assuming that you sorting the tables and not the rows of data).  I would print each table on a separate piece of paper and then find a table and just sort them manually.

Comment: Many text editors can sort lines of  text. If each row of the table is only in one line of text , this should be enough.

Comment: @Fran For example ??

Comment: @karu In Linux for example vim, joe, nedit,  pluma (with plugin),  vim, geany (sending text to `sort` Linux command) ... Libreoffice, ...

Comment: @karu: On windows, linux or Mac OSX, you can also use emacs. You highloght the region, you´d like to sort and do "M-x sort-lines". This will sort you the lines you want. And if you use tables heavily, i would consider, in emacs, the org-mode, which makes the creating, handling and working with tables easy as the work with a pencil (or something). It is worth to learn emacs, at least the commands you need, and also the org-mode from emacs.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the job (script and test file below):

```
pdflatex test.tex
python ltx-table_sort.py
pdflatex test.tex
```

#### `test.tex`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table0_unsorted.tex}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    Language  & Syllable & IPA & VIS & VDS & CS &  CVS \\ \hline
    Malayalam & & & & & & \\
    Tamil     & & & & & & \\
    Kannada   & & & & & & \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{table1_unsorted.tex}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    Language  & Syllable & IPA & VIS & VDS & CS &  CVS \\ \hline
    Malayalam & & & & & & \\
    Tamil     & & & & & & \\
    Kannada   & & & & & & \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{./table0.tex}{%
  \begin{table}
  \label{tab:first}
    \input table0\relax
  \caption{Table contains syllable in IPA, VIS-Vowel Independent Syllable, VDS-Vowel Dependent Symbol, CS-Consonant Symbol, and CVS  Consonant with Vowel Symbol.}
\end{table}   
}{}

\IfFileExists{./table1.tex}{%
  \begin{table}
  \label{tab:first}
    \input table1\relax
  \caption{Table contains syllable in IPA, VIS-Vowel Independent Syllable, VDS-Vowel Dependent Symbol, CS-Consonant Symbol, and CVS  Consonant with Vowel Symbol.}
\end{table}   
}{}
\end{document}
```

#### `ltx-table_sort.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

for fn in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(fn):
        if fn.startswith('table'):
            if '_unsorted' in fn:
                fno = fn[:-13]+'.tex'
                file_input = open( fn, 'r')
                file_output = open( fno, 'w')

                arr_tmp = []

                for line in file_input:
                    if line.lstrip().startswith('\\begin{tabular}'):
                        str_begin = line
                    elif line.lstrip().startswith('Language'):
                        str_lang = line.lstrip()
                    elif line.lstrip().startswith('\\end{tabular}'):
                        str_end = line
                    else:
                        arr_tmp.append( line.lstrip() )

                file_output.write( str_begin+str_lang )

                for a in sorted(arr_tmp):
                    file_output.write( a )

                file_output.write( str_end )
                file_input.close()
                file_output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to import your table [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/) and copy-paste it into a spreadsheet applications, sort it and then do it all in reverse.

Comment: Could you delete the answer? so that  I can delete the question